# Streaming replication setup, sane setup?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, failover

Not being a DBA as main profession, I would like to know if the following assumptions are true. I have been searching the net for days and I think I have understand it correctly, but I would like to hear the response from people when faced with my exact configuration.

I want to utilize streaming replication, which I have a working setup for.

I have turned off WAL archiving, since I believe that wal_keep_segments will contain enough backlog to get a slave up to date if necessary (700, you might think this high, I just calculated how much "buffer" I could spare for replication backlog, please tell me if this is the wrong approach).

I have the same configuration on master and slave, which includes the following:

```
wal_level = hot_standby    
hot_standby = on  #(this is ignored on master, as I understand it?)
```

Now, the main question is the first entry here, I could theoretically set this to minimal on the slave, correct? However, I'm thinking for ease of failover, I should keep it this way?

Finally, I never specify restore_command in my recovery.conf, because as I have understood it, this is for log shipping (when rsyncing the WAL files between the two nodes or similar), or if I were to bring back a slave node from a long disconnect and archive_mode was on. 12 GB of WAL segments should be good for at least a week (unless I do some big restore of a DB), and I assume that all segments that are in pg_xlog will be streamed to the slave upon reconnect if it is behind?

And finally, what would be a good way to surveillance that the replication works as it should? I know about repmgr, but it would be nice to be aware of how the surveillance would consider the slave to be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad topic, and not one I am going to cover in detail here. One point to note however: in my experience, SR can occasionally break due to network issues between datacenters (or ever servers), so disabling log shipping isn't a good idea unless you truly don't have the bandwidth to spare between master and slave(s).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But am I right to assume that if streaming replication isn't working (because of network issues), log shipping wouldn't work either? And, if keep_segments is high enough, it will be able to get back on track as long as I still have the segments for it? Because the archive would take up at least the same amount of space as the segments would do?

Comment: If the network was severely impacted, yes, log shipping would experience the same problem as streaming replication (no data goes over the wire), but I should have been more explicit. The network connectivity problems I was referring to would be enough to cause streaming replication to fall behind and fail, but this is where the log shipping comes into play. Assuming you have set wal_keep_segments high enough, once the network is okay, the WAL segments will ship to your slave and your db will be brought up to date again. When I experienced this in 9.0, SR did not restart automatically (IIRC).